# SELECT-Запрос к таблице не возвращает все записи

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

На сервере пытаюсь получить данные с таблицы.

```
result = DBexecutor.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM mappacks WHERE ROWID >="+startWith+" AND ROWID <="+endWith+";" );
        while (result.next()){
            MapPackStructure mapPack = gson.fromJson((result.getString("JSON")), MapPackStructure.class);

            TreeMap pack = new TreeMap(){{
                put("ID", mapPack.getID());
                put("name", mapPack.getName());
                put("author", mapPack.getAuthor());
                put("preview", "/static/mappack/"+mapPack.getID()+"/png");
            }};

            ArrayList<TreeMap> levels = new ArrayList<>();

            for(Integer levelID: mapPack.getMaps()) {
                ResultSet innerResult;

                innerResult = DBexecutor.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM levels WHERE ID =" + levelID + ";");
                while (innerResult.next()) {
                    levels.add(new TreeMap() {{
                        put("ID", innerResult.getString("ID"));
                        put("name", innerResult.getString("name"));
                        put("author", innerResult.getString("Author"));
                    }});
                }
            }

            pack.put("levels", levels);

            rendered += config.renderTemplate(template, pack);

            System.out.println(rendered);

            DBexecutor.close();
        }  //startWith = 1 endWith = 5
```

Всего в таблице 3 ряда, получаю на выход только одну запись, при этом внутренний запрос работает отлично.

Что интересно, даже если запрос будет "SELECT * FROM mappacks", получу я только одну запись

Comment: А что делает метод `DBexecutor.close()`? Не закрывает ли он случайно все ресурсы, в том числе и `result` (или соединение, в рамках которого был получен `result`)?

Comment: Roman прав. ResultSet живет при активном подключении и хранит данные только о текущей строке. Вы закрываете соединение и в итоге не можете запросить следующую строку.

Comment: нет, не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось просто. SQLite не дает делать запрос при незакрытом запросе (запрос в запросе) в одну БД. Единственное решение - перейти на cassandra и подобные